# How do I add the number of rows shown in a view to a menu link?

Tags: views, routes

I want to add the number of rows shown in a view to a menu link, something as follows, for example.

> Companies(29) | Products(152) | Customers(522) | Orders(9888) ..

How can I achieve this?

[image: How can I achieve this?]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a view, assuming each item is a content type.

Create a new view of Content as an unformatted list of fields. Under 'Advanced' set Use Aggregation to Yes.

Under fields delete the title field, and add Content:Type and Content:NID.

Configure the Content:Type field as no label and "group by" under Aggregation Settings. Under 'Rewrite Results' check 'Output this field as a link', set it to replace spaces with dashes and to convert to lower case. In the path enter something like "list/[type]", depending on your desired target.

Configure the Content:NID field as no label, and add the prefic " (" and the suffix")". Set it to 'Count' under Aggregation Settings.

Use CSS to have both fields `float:left;` to line them up.

You can leave the view unsorted or sort by Content:NID->COUNT or by Content:Type. You should leave the filter for Published nodes, and you can add a filter to restrict the content types which will appear.

Then place the block where you want the menu to appear.

Comment: see this image please and tell me if you got my idea ??

Comment: this is image http://i.stack.imgur.com/kpqSe.jpg

Comment: I have your idea, and gave you a simple solution which is predicated on the menu items being content types. Easily done with an aggregated view. If the source of your information is not a view, then it becomes more complex. If you are creating the menu in code, then you will have to write a callback function to assemble the count information for the menu titles.

Comment: i found module do this but i search now for this module in the google but don't get any result :(

Comment: i found the solution after search in the web
use the  [Menu Badges][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.org/project/menu_badges

Comment: Ecellent! Interesting module. I was not aware of it. Thank you.